# Group by dataframe and split to columns

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the output of the dataframe, im able to  publish

```
df2 = df.groupby(['id1','id2']).size().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['id1','id2','Count']
print (df2)
```

```html
  id1                         id2                  Count
   7780379  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000      1
   7780379  72b9f501-6d48-4a37-8f3a-ff4e5fb6ec8d     19
```

im trying to add the condition is any id2 that belongs to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 is an invalid count , Below is the expected result

```
     id1    ValidCount  InvalidCount
     7780379      19         1
```

Please share if any pointers.

Comment: maybe use replace? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_sum`:

```
out = df.groupby(['id1', df['id2']!='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'])['Count'] \
        .sum().unstack().rename(columns={True: 'ValidCount', False: 'InvalidCount'})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
id2      InvalidCount  ValidCount
id1                              
7780379             1          19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the final output from `df` directly, without needs of `df2`:

```
valids = np.where(df['id2']=='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 
                  'InvalidCount', 'ValidCount')
df.groupby(['id1', valids]).size().unstack('id2').reset_index()
```

Comment: Hong  , below is the output , but looking for output as mentioned in above  

 id1             level_1         0
7780379 InvalidCount 1
7780379 ValidCount 19

Comment: sorry, im still learning how to format output .